# Instances for type with nested parameter

Tags: haskell

I can derive Eq in this example:

```
data A f t = A (f t) deriving (Eq)
```

But in this example:

```
data B f t = B (f (f t)) deriving (Eq)
```

I get this error:

```
> No instance for (Eq (f (f t)))
>   arising from the first field of ‘B’ (type ‘f (f t)’)
> Possible fix:
>   use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
>     so you can specify the instance context yourself
```

This works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
...
data B f t = B (f (f t))
deriving instance (Eq (f (f t)), Eq (f t)) => Eq (B f t)
```

but I've read that using `UndecidableInstances` can be a bad idea, and I'm not sure when it's ok and when it's not.

I tried this, and it works:

```
data B f t = B (f (f t))

instance (Eq1 f, Eq t) => (Eq (B f t)) where
  (B x) == (B y) = eq1 x y
```

but I also want to make `B` an instance of `NFData`, `Read` and `Show` and I don't want to write the `Read`, `Show` and `NFData` instances as well as `Eq1`, `Show1`, and `NFData1` instances and a class for `NFData1`.

I have 3 questions:

1. Why does the first example compile but the second doesn't?
2. Is this a bad time to use UndecidableInstances?
3. Is there any way to do what I want without writing all those instances?

Comment: Note that you don't actually need `Eq (f t)`. Just `deriving instance Eq (f (f t)) => Eq (B f t)` will work. (It still needs `UndecidableInstances` though.)

Comment: @JosephSible I was unable to get it to compile without both `Eq (f (f t))` and `Eq (f t)`

Comment: Are you sure?  See my answer -- it worked for me.

Comment: @JosephSible, @K. A. Buhr, Oops, my mistake. This was a simplified example and in the original version it was `data B f t = B (f (f t)) (f t)`. That one required the extra `(f t)` in the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact example appears in the GHC manual in the section [Inferred context for deriving clauses](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.4/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#inferred-context-for-deriving-clauses).  As documented there, GHC takes a conservative position when inferring contexts for deriving instances by requiring that each constraint in the inferred context must consist only of type variables with no repetitions.  Since `(f (f t))` has the repeated type variable `f`, it is rejected.  Note that the following would be accepted:

```
data C f g t = C (f (g t)) deriving (Eq)
```

The solution given in the manual is to use a standalone deriving clause, as you've done.  As pointed out in a comment, the following is sufficient:

```
deriving instance Eq (f (f t)) => Eq (B f t)
```

However, because the type variable `f` appears more often in the constraint than in the "instance head" `Eq  (B f t)`, it violates the rules documented in [Instance termination rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.4/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#instance-termination-rules) (specifically, the first Paterson Condition) which guarantee the type checker won't loop.  Because these rules are sufficient but not necessary, there are many instance declarations that work fine even though they violate the rules.  Turning on `UndecidableInstances` allows them.

There's no particular reason not to turn on `UndecidableInstances`.  In a worst case, you'll create an instance that causes the type checker to loop, and compilation will fail with an error advising you to increase the stack depth with `-freduction-depth={n}` (which won't help if you have a genuine loop).  Note that this is only a compile-time issue.  If code compiles with `UndecidableInstances`, you don't have to worry about some future runtime danger.

Note that I didn't need to turn on `FlexibleContexts`.  The following works fine:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

data B f t = B (f (f t))
deriving instance Eq (f (f t)) => Eq (B f t)
deriving instance Read (f (f t)) => Read (B f t)
deriving instance Show (f (f t)) => Show (B f t)
```

For manually derived instances, the following seems to work and doesn't require `NFData1` or similar:

```
instance NFData (f (f t)) => NFData (B f t) where
  rnf (B fft) = rnf fft
```